# I cannot parse Json data from retrofit what's the problem?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit, android-livedata

Here's my code

```
interface ApiService {

@POST("sms-otp/request")
suspend fun loginTest(@Body testRequest: TestRequest): Response<TestResponse>
}


data class TestResponse(

@SerializedName("otp")
@Expose
var otp : String? = null,

@Expose
@SerializedName("otpId")
var otpId: Int? = null
)
```

Logic -

```
  loginRepository.loginTest(testRequest.phoneNumber!!).let {
        if (it.isSuccessful) {

            _res.postValue(Resource.success(it.body()))
            Log.d("_res", it.body().toString())
            Log.d("_res" , _res.value.toString())
            Log.d("_res", _res.value?.data.toString())

        } else {
            _res.postValue(Resource.error(it.errorBody().toString(), null))
        }
    }
```

Here is my Log , I think response code is 201, maybe success but no data in my model... please help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRGr7.png)

Comment: Nodes "otp" and "otpId" don't belong to the root JSON node, they are placed inside "data".  Therefore, class `TestResponse` should have a field called `data` with nested fields `otp` and `otpId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a response from the server, as `okhttp` logging is showing. But, retrofit is not able to map it. As you have the wrong kotlin data class for the response.

```
{
  "code": "0000",
  "message": "ok",
  "data": {
    "otpId": 21,
    "otp": "518793"
  }
}
```

Response has `otpData` inside `data` object, but your `TestResponse` only contains `otp` properties.

For retrofit to map correctly, you have to define two data classes, one for the parent response and one for the `otpData`

Change `TestResponse.kt` to this

```
data class TestResponse(
    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    val code: String,
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    val otpData: OtpData,
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    val message: String
)
```

Now, create`OtpData.kt`

```
data class OtpData(
    @SerializedName("otp")
    @Expose
    val otp: String,
    @SerializedName("otpId")
    @Expose
    val otpId: Int
)
```